# How do I work around a "RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Hash" when trying to delete records on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

At my Rails console on Heroku, I am trying to do a simple array iteration and delete the record if a certain condition exists, and I am running into that error.

This is what I am doing:

```
irb(main):044:0> a.first
=> #<Activity id: 1, trackable_id: 3, trackable_type: "Node", owner_id: 5, owner_type: "User", key: "node.create", parameters: {}, recipient_id: nil, recipient_type: nil, created_at: "2014-07-30 11:22:15", updated_at: "2014-07-30 11:22:15", read_status: 0>
irb(main):045:0> a.first.trackable.nil?
=> false
irb(main):046:0> a.second.trackable.nil?
=> true
irb(main):061:0> a.each do |x|
irb(main):062:1* if x.trackable.nil?
irb(main):063:2> x.destroy
irb(main):064:2> x.save
irb(main):065:2> end
irb(main):066:1> end
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Hash
```

Thoughts on how I can achieve this?

If I leave off the `x.save` it doesn't get rid of the record it seems.

Comment: destroy will delete the record from the db, but will not clear x from memory.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `.save` on a destroyed record. Once you've called `.destroy` on the record, it's been removed from the database already; there's no use calling `.save` on it. If you're basing your determination of whether it's been destroyed by whether you still have access to it in Ruby's memory, you can call `.destroyed?` on a record to find out whether it's been destroyed or not.